# Force to close the app if there's no internet connection in webview

Tags: android, android-webview

Using an Android WebView, how can I force the application to close if the phone has no internet connection?

Alternatively, if this is not possible, is there any way to show a 404 html page if user is offline.

Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.show_web_view);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        startWebView("http://example.com/appsite/index.php");

    }

    private void startWebView(String url) {

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {      
                ProgressDialog progressDialog;

                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {              
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }

                public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
                    if (progressDialog == null) {

                        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                        progressDialog.show();
                    }
                }
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    try{
                        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            progressDialog = null;
                        }
                    }catch(Exception exception){
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }); 
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 

        webView.loadUrl(url);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to try some code or search better, this kind of question was already done a lot here in this community.

Well, below is some code that can help you in your problem:

Create a method that check if has or not connectivity

```
public boolean hasConnectivity(Context context) {
    if (context != null) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                        Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager
                .getActiveNetworkInfo();

        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable()
                && networkInfo.isConnected();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then, call in your onCreate method:

```
if (hasConnectivity(this)) {
        startWebView("http://example.com/appsite/index.php");
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "you do not have connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Remember to add in your AndroidManifest.xml this permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```